# Copying from memory stream to File Stream fails

Tags: c#, filestream, memorystream

I am attempting to copy a memory stream to a file stream. I noticed that the output exe is corrupt when decrypted. I am certain there is no issue with the decrypt function. Here is the code

```
 private MemoryStream My_Encrypt(Stream inputFile)
        {

                //FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create);
                MemoryStream fsCrypt = new MemoryStream();

                RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

                CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

                int data;
                while ((data = inputFile.ReadByte()) != -1)
                    cs.WriteByte((byte)data);

                inputFile.Flush();

                return fsCrypt;

        }


        MemoryStream ms = My_Encrypt(bundleStream);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        FileStream atest = new FileStream("c:\\Somefile.exe",FileMode.Create);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        ms.CopyTo(atest);

        atest.Close();
```

**More details:**
The reason I am saying that the memory stream method is not working is because in `My_Encrypt` method  if I replace fsCrypt with FileStream instead of Memory Stream and close fsCrypt at the end of the method and then reopen the saved file and write it to another file it works. My question is why is the memory stream method not working.

Comment: Why you call inputFile.Flush()? I think it should be cs.Flush()

Comment: @Igor I read that  `.close()` calls flush before closing

Comment: Sorry but I ask about inputFile.Flush()

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca I am getting the same behaviour when I remove `inputFile.flush()`

Comment: MSDN says you MUST call `.Clear` on the `CryptoStream` when you are done using it.  `.Clear` will close and flush the stream for you. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I believe @ArturoMenchaca  means replace `inputFile.Flush()` with `cs.Flush()` (2nd to last line in method `My_Encrypt`).

Comment: yes, this is what I try to say

Comment: @Igor According to msdn, it should be `cs.Clear`.

Comment: @BradleyUffner - its a wrapper around the `Dispose` implementation (*according to the documentation*). Should be good for when you are writing to a file but when you are writing to a MemoryStream and you want to return that stream then calling clear will close/dispose of that underlying MemoryStream as well.

Comment: I tried doing that still no difference

Comment: One more attempt, try [FlushFinalBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.flushfinalblock(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of Flush on `cs`.

Comment: @Igor `FlushFinalBlock` did the trick. Could you put that down as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to call [FlushFinalBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.flushfinalblock(v=vs.110).aspx) on the CryptoStream.

```
private MemoryStream My_Encrypt(Stream inputFile)
{
    //FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create);
    MemoryStream fsCrypt = new MemoryStream();

    RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    int data;
    while ((data = inputFile.ReadByte()) != -1)
        cs.WriteByte((byte)data);

    cs.FlushFinalBlock();

    return fsCrypt;
}
```